# Restar 2 Columnas de diferentes tablas que comparten el mismo ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Necesito llegar a hacer un registro de objetos que tengo en el almacén y tengo 3 tablas, una de entradas, otra de salidas y una de almacén. Necesito que las cantidades de entradas de un mismo objeto se resten con las cantidades de salidas de un mismo objeto. Eso debe pasar con cada tipo de objeto que tengo registrado, pero no estoy seguro como hacerlo.
Aquó el ejemplo

Entradas

```
EntradaID | cantidad | ProductoCode | 
    1           2          abc     
    2           3          abc     
    3           4          asd     
    4           2          asd     
    5           3          zxc
```

Salidas

```
SalidaID | cantidad | ProductoCode | 
    1           1          abc     
    2           1          abc     
    3           2          asd     
    4           3          asd     
    5           3          zxc
```

Después de hacer la resta de las entradas con las salidas, quiero que el resultado de mi resta se Registre en la tabla `inventario` en la columna `Cantidad`, con su respectivo `ProductCode`.

```
InventarioID | cantidad | ProductoCode | 
    1           3          abc     
    2           1          asd     
    3           0          zxc
```

Ojo que el `ProductoCode` es de otra tabla no mencionada, donde esta almacenado el significado de cada `ProductCode`.

Entonces necesito un código que pueda desarrollar lo previamente visto.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. En su estado actual tu pregunta se lee como una solicitud de realizar tu tarea escolar. Sugiero que leas [ask] y que hagas preguntas puntuales sobre tus dudas, demostrando el esfuerzo que has realizado hasta ahora por resolver la tarea tu mismo. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY Entradas.ProductoCode
        ) AS InventarioId
    ,Entradas.sumCantidad - Salidas.sumCantidad
    ,Entradas.ProductoCode
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(cantidad) AS sumCantidad
        ,ProductoCode
    FROM Entradas
    GROUP BY ProductoCode
    ) Entradas
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(cantidad) AS sumCantidad
        ,ProductoCode
    FROM Salidas
    GROUP BY ProductoCode
    ) Salidas ON Entradas.ProductoCode = Salidas.ProductoCode
```

Primero sumamos las cantidades que tenemos por cada ProductoCode tanto en Entradas y Salidas, posteriormente restamos las Salidas a las Entradas.

Para el Campo inventarioID, se ha incluido el ROW_NUMBER que numera automaticamente los registros.